# UWP Printing: FontFamily, problems in printing

Tags: printing, fonts, uwp, font-family

Believe it or not, I have a UWP app that needs to print multi-part forms on a dot matrix printer. We got a print driver, and we can print just fine from Word/Notepad. However, from my application the fonts look really bad. The test docs used 'Courier New' at 12 pitch. This is exactly what I have in my style for the printed information. However, when it comes from my app, the font looks nasty. I have tried numerous font family combinations and nothing seems to help.

Any ideas/pointers would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please detail "bad","nasty"? For example, did doc printed looks faint or too light? What's the result if you print the test docs to pdf format? Does this issue only occur with `Courier New` and `12 pitch`? How about other font families and font sizes?

Comment: The fonts are garbled/fuzzy like the printer is interpolating the font and since its an old dot matrix printer, not really well. Will see if I can attach an example of the printout. If I print, from my application to .pdf, i get the same result. I also tried the UWP sample  print application and got the same results. So, I think its in the way the sample app (which I copied) is printing.

Comment: https://1drv.ms/b/s!AkqPO4zhjRj2kc5xqsMW3cqRGFFnhA

Comment: That link is to a capture of the output of the UWP print sample, first page.

Comment: So if you print from Word there is no such issue,only UWP has, right? How about print from edge? Did you have another printer for testing?

Comment: I think the problem lies in the printer drivers. Most of the printout looks fuzzy/messed up. I ordered a new dot matrix printer for testing, should have it this week. Will post an update in a few days.

Comment: I purchased a new Oki 186 dot matrix printer. Using WordPad, the print is mostly garbage unless I select Courier New, then it looks good. When I print a test page, that looks fantastic with proportional fonts and graphics. I tried the POS Sample app, but apparently this does not come up as a POS printer. So, it looks like the print driver is okay, but the way/data that I am sending is a problem. The UWP print sample renders with an RichTextBlock and I am wondering if that is the problem.

Comment: If as you concerned, you can try print `Textbox`, or try an image to see if have differences with word.

Comment: I discovered the problem, turns out the "in box" drivers for this printer on Windows 10 are not worthy. Speaking with Okidata, they directed me to a Win7 set of drivers and now everything works great.

Thanks very much for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was the printer driver. Switching to the Windows Update driver specific for that printer solved all the problems. Wish the inbox driver had worked, but happy it is resolved.